# Given java enum class, find enum by value

Tags: java, generics, enums

A common desire in my project is to find an enum when given one of its constructed values. For example:

```java
public enum Animal {
    DOG("bark"),
    CAT("meow");
    
    public final String sound;

    Animal(String sound) {
        this.sound = sound;
    }

    public String getSound() {
        return sound;
    }
}
```

If given the string `"meow"`, I want to get a `CAT`

The easy solution is to write a search method that iterates over the values of the Enum

```java
public static Animal getBySound(String sound) {
    for(Animal e : values()){
        if(e.sound.equals(sound)){
            return e;
        }
    }
}
```

But this has to be done individually, for every enum defined. **Is there a way, given an Enum class and a method that gets a field's value, you can get the enum who's specified field matches the input?**

Possible signature:

```java
public static <T extends Enum<T>, V> Optional<T> findEnumByValue(Class<T> enumClass, Function<T, V> fieldGetter, V valueToMatch)
```

The closest I've gotten is this, but having the first argument be `Enum[]` is just one step away from being fully type-safe (as the method could be supplied an arbitrary array of enums)

```java
public static <T extends Enum<T>, V> Optional<T> findEnumByValue(T[] enums, Function<T, V> fieldGetter, V valueMatch) {
    return Arrays.stream(enums).filter(element -> Objects.equals(fieldGetter.apply(element), valueMatch)).findFirst();
}

// Example usage
Animal animal = findEnumByValue(Animal.values(), Animal::getSound, "meow").orElse(CAT);
```

It seems that part of the difficulty is that the static method `values()` that is a part of every Enum class is not accessible through the `Class` object.

Comment: BTW do not use `==` to compare strings

Comment: And for the "why" give https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java a read. But the tl;dr is "if you're comparing objects, including strings (which are _not_ a primitive in Java) use the `.equals` method".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> It seems that part of the difficulty is that the static method values() that is a part of every Enum class is not accessible through the Class object.

This is not an issue: you can use [`EnumSet.allOf(Class)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api//java.base/java/util/EnumSet.html#allOf(java.lang.Class)) to access all enum values for a given enum `Class`.  You can then use that like a normal [`Set`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api//java.base/java/util/Set.html), including streaming over it.

```
Optional<Animal> anAnimalThatMeows = 
    EnumSet
        .allOf(Animal.class)
        .stream()
        .filter(( Animal animal ) -> animal.getSound().equals("meow"))
        .findAny() ;
```

See this [code run at Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/gUKqcQ).

Comment: i.e. `EnumSet.allOf(clazz).stream().filter(e -> e.sound().equals(“miaow”)).findFirst()`.

Comment: @user207421 I suspect you meant to use [`Stream#findAny`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api//java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#findAny()) rather than `findFirst`. The `findFirst` method imposes ordering which is unnecessary here.

Comment: @BasilBourque Well I didn't, but I accept the correction ;-) Thanks for the info. I wonder if `EnumSet.stream()` really is unordered?

Comment: @user207421 Does not really matter. Calling `findAny` gives permission to the implementation to use any arbitrary algorithm to find any matching object without paying attention to its position in the original order (if any). And this may increase performance when using a parallelized stream.

Comment: @BasilBourque OK Tks again.

Comment: I'd tend to push back a little on `findAny` versus `findFirst`.  For the size of a typical enum, parallelism is likely to be bad anyway unless your filter is extremely expensive; there's unlikely to be a difference in the implementation for sequential.  I admit I'd tend to write neither, but `collect(MoreCollectors.onlyElement())` from Guava, to actively assert that one and only one enum value matches.

Comment: I guess I'm confused.  The OP said of their method: *`"But this has to be done individually, for every enum defined."`*  But you're specifically calling out `Animal.class` in the stream.  How is this any different than streaming `Animal.values()` or using the OP's method.  It is still `Animal` specific.

Comment: @WJS I see your point, upon rereading the Question. But the OP *did* accept this Answer.

Comment: @BasilBourque Yes.  It was accepted.  Which is why I was hoping someone could explain to me what I am missing.  LoL.

Comment: @WJS The question text says: "...having the first argument be Enum[] is just one step away from being fully type-safe (as the method could be supplied an arbitrary array of enums)."  Supplying the `Class` ensures that the entire set of constants for a given enum is considered, not just whichever happen to be passed in the input array.  The last sentence emphasizes this aspect, that a way to go from the `Class` to the set of constants would meet the OP's need.

Answer (score 4):

Without any comment on your general approach:

> It seems that part of the difficulty is that the static method values() that is a part of every Enum class is not accessible through the Class object.

[`Class.getEnumConstants()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getEnumConstants--)

Returns an array of the defined objects of this enum class (or `null` if not an enum).

Answer (score 1):

If you have similar enums which are all based on a single value, you can let them implement a common interface:

```java
public interface ValueAware<V> {
    V getValue();
}
```

And then use the following method to find instances based on a value:

```java
public static <T extends Enum<T> & ValueAware<V>, V> Optional<T> findEnumByValue(Class<T> enumClass, V valueToMatch) {
    return EnumSet.allOf(enumClass).stream()
            .filter(element -> Objects.equals(element.getValue(), valueToMatch))
            .findAny();
}
```

The example enum would look like this:

```java
public enum Animal implements ValueAware<String> {
    DOG("bark"),
    CAT("meow");
    
    private final String sound;

    Animal(String sound) {
        this.sound = sound;
    }

    @Override
    public String getValue() {
        return sound;
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```java
Optional<Animal> cat = findEnumByValue(Animal.class, "meow");
```